# MYSQL PHP HTML Load image from database to website

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, src

Hello I have in my DB a column called capalivro that has my image paths. 
I want to make the img src the content of that column, but I'm not succeding in doing this since I don't know how to put that PHP var in the HTML. 
This way I tried doesn't work because the php doesn't work because of the quotation marks.

```
<?php while ($livro = mysql_fetch_assoc($livrotodos)) { ?>
        <div class="large-2 columns">
          <div class="livro">
            <div class="livro-overlay">
              <h3><?php echo $livro['nomelivro'] ?></h3>
            </div>
            <img src= "<?php $livro['capalivro']?>" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } 
        ?>
```

Comment: You are missing `echo` here `<?php $livro['capalivro']?>`

Comment: RTFM and oh BTW practice your English. This is the kind of error I always stumble upon during development every day. Try <?= instead of <?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your line containing the `img src=` bit to:

```
<img src="<?php echo $livro['capalivro']?>" />
```

without the `echo` part, it won't display the "string" from the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
</div>
        <img src= "<?php $livro['capalivro']?>" />
      </div>
```

should be:

```
</div>
        <img src= <?php echo "\"". $livro['capalivro']."\""?> />
      </div>
```